# How to store multiple values in a single column in Core data iOS objective c

Tags: ios, core-data

I have to store multiple values in a single column or field in the core data. How do I do it in iOS objective c? Suppose I have a database with 2 columns C1 and C2. C1 I will store some integer(some id). In C2 I need to store values something like  a1,a2,a3,a4... How do I do this?

Comment: You can do that by storing  a string with comma separator just like this
"a1,a2,a3"

Comment: or you can store that using array!

Comment: hey how about saving data as json

Comment: Consider normalizing your database.  a1..a4 may belong in their own related table.